# How to remove a "frequented" tag?

Tags: support, tags, user-interface

Edit: Found a exact duplicate over on meta.StackOverflow: [How do I remove a frequented tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74943/how-do-i-remove-a-frequented-tag)

In the upper right corner of the main page (below Ask Question) it says:

```
Frequented Tags
[firefox]
```

This seems to be resposible for ugly blue bars across the question list (please correct me if this is false), so I'd like to remove it, but doesnt seem to show up under prefs.

Edit: screenshot:
[image]

Comment: could you add a screenshot ? I've seen the frequented tags, but never the "ugly blue bars"

Comment: @Sathya, added; in retrostect I probably should have cropped that more, will fix if anyone cares.

Comment: I don't see the ugly blue bars, with the exception of the blue highlight on featured questions tab slightly spillng over - are you talking about this? Please include which OS & browser you're using.

Comment: @Sathya, that is the ugly blue bar. See recent edit though.

Comment: scratch first half of previous comment, thought you said "frequented questions" rather than "featured questions tab".

Comment: Is this only visible if you have no manually favorites tags? I have never seen these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen the Frequent tag, because The "Ugly Blue Bars", can also be questions that are tagged for your Favorited tags. The system highlights these favorite tags for you, making it easier to find questions with that tag in the list.

What happens if you set up a favorite, instead of having the system pick something you were at a few times. ( I had a favorited item before I even made the first post )

They may not be pretty, but they can be pretty useful.  Using a combination of "ignored" tags, and "favorite" tags , you get to see the whole list, ignored items are ghosted, and favorite items are highlighted/colorised.

Like it said at stack overflow, set one measly Tag as Ignored or Favorited.  Ignored does not make it dissapear completly, and there is probably a lesser used tag, that wouldn't cut into your list to much.  157 pages of tags, mabey you can find one thing to ignore and have ghosted slightly?